# How to send data through server with angular using express? 404 error

Tags: angular, express

I am trying to get user registration details from my frontend using angular and sending it through a server (express). I am not sure what I am doing wrong. any solution?
I named the path of the register page to "registration" which is why I am using '/registration' for my post api.

`user-register.component.ts` :

```
  registerUser(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const target = event.target;
    const registerName = target.registerName.value;
    const registerEmail = target.registerEmail.value;
    const registerPassword = target.registerPassword.value;
    const companyName = target.companyName.value;
    const companyCategory = target.companyCategory.value;


    this.auth.registerUser(registerName, registerEmail, registerPassword, companyName, companyCategory).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      /*if (data.success) {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      }*/
    });
    console.log(registerName)
  }
```

`auth.service.ts:`

```
  registerUser(registerName, registerEmail, registerPassword, companyName, companyCategory) {
    return this.http.post('/registration', {
      registerName,
      registerEmail,
      registerPassword,
      companyName,
      companyCategory
    });
  }
```

`server folder :
index.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/registration', (req, res) => {

console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen (4200, ()=> console.log('Server listen at 4200'));
```

Comment: This will help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444033/express-accessing-angular-http-post-data

Comment: thanks, but I still have the same problem

Comment: just a general advice can you convert the body in angular http post to a proper defined JSON object lets say 
`body={`
       `regName:registerName,`
      `regEmail:registerEmail,`
      `regPass:registerPassword,`
      `companyName:companyName,`
      `companyCategory:companyCategory`
    `}`
Also, 404 means resource you're trying to access is not found `
console.log(req.body);` does this line execute?  @HusseinMenshawi

Comment: I see,
and no the console.log(req.body) does not execute

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the issue was with the auth.service.ts : 
I changed:

```
registerUser(registerName, registerEmail, registerPassword, companyName, companyCategory) {
    return this.http.post('/registration', {
      registerName,
      registerEmail,
      registerPassword,
      companyName,
      companyCategory
    });
  }
```

to this

```
registerUser(registerName, registerEmail, registerPassword, companyName, companyCategory) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:SERVERPORT/registration', {
      registerName,
      registerEmail,
      registerPassword,
      companyName,
      companyCategory
    });
  }
```