# Unable to receive body data from Angular HTTPClient module on node.js express

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have a frontend in Angular and a backend in node.js with express.

I am doing a POST request in Angular like so:

```
this.userDetails = {
  address: {
    city: "City"
    country: "CH"
    number: "8"
    road: "Road"
    zip: "1020"
  },
  details: {
    2FA: false
    email: "test@user.io"
    gender: "0"
    name: "User"
    surname: "Name"

  }
}
this.http.post(
  environment.paymentHook + '/customercreate',
  this.userDetails
).subscribe(
  res => resolve(res),
  err => resolve(err)
);
```

receiving it like so in the back:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.options('/customercreate', cors(corsOptionsDelegate), function (req, res) { 
  res.end(); 
});
app.post('/customercreate', cors(corsOptionsDelegate), async (request, response) => {
  const body = request.body; // --> this appears empty {} when it should have the this.userDetails content
});
```

Anybody knows what is my issue here?

Comment: What is `this.userDetails` when the call is made?

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444033/express-accessing-angular-http-post-data

Comment: Try looking in your web browsers network tab and see if the http call looks correct. Your angular code looks correct assuming `environment.paymentHook` is right.

Comment: @MikeOne This is a really old answer. With the newest version of express there is no need to use bodyParser

Comment: @JimmyArroyo Yes, I receive the request on the server and am able to console.log a few things. But the req.body appears empty like `{}`

Comment: Can you see the body in the network request in the browser console too?

Comment: @JimmyArroyo yes, the body appears in the request payload

Comment: What's the content type for the request? Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: I faced the same problem. And it was caused because body contents was sent as custom JSON, like your `this.userDetails`. And this is *sometimes* not liked by express. Try converting that custom JSON into a `FormData` object. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783108/convert-js-object-to-form-data